# How can I access/open a serial port simultaneously by two applications in c++

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port, hyperterminal

When I use an application [hercules_3-2-5](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.htm)
 and open a serial port then that port cannot be opened by any other application till its freed by the port-opening application.
The problem is that on new laptops there is no serial port and I want my c++ application to open the same port which was opened by (hercules_3-2-5) and communicate with it.

Is there a way to open/communicate on same serial port which is already opened by another application?

Comment: Erm, wait, if your laptop doesn't have any serial ports then how do you expect this "hercules" program to work?  Google "serial port monitor" to shop for products that let you snoop on serial ports.

Comment: @HansPassant I am using bluetooth serial port (COM3) in my case. What I am asking is a help on accessing the serial port. Like the port monitoring software do [like the one mentioned below 1]. They can open the same port that other applications are using and can send data on behalf of that application. [1]: http://www.techspot.com/downloads/780-free-serial-port-monitor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not have the same serial port opened 2 programs.